# CSS Changing The Look of A Table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, width

I have a table on my website which contains the columns: User, Title, Description, Join, Update, Delete.

The "User" column's width is way too big as well as the "Title" column. I need help with CSS to set them to something smaller without affecting the width of the other columns as they are perfect as is.

My Code:

```
<?php
echo "<table>
   <tr>
   <th>User</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th></th>
   <th>Join</th>
   <th>Update</th>
   <th>Delete</th>
   </tr>";

while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData))
    {
    echo "<form action=findGroup.php method=post>";
    echo "<div class=joinLink>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value='" . $record['form_user'] . "'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value='" . $record['form_name'] . "'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value='" . $record['form_description'] . "'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value='" . $record['form_id'] . "'/></td>";
    echo "<td><a class=joinLink type=text name=join href='http://localhost:3000'>Join</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value='Update" . "'/> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value='Delete" . "'/> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
    }

echo "</table>";
```

CSS:

```
 table {
     width: 100%;
     font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
     text-align: centre;
     align: centre;
}
 input {
     width: 100%;
     font: 13px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
     text-align: centre;
     align: centre;
     height: auto;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 th {
     align: centre;
     text-align: centre;
     background-color: #4D5960;
     color: white;
}
 tr {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
 input[type="text"]{
    width:100% !important;
     line-height:30px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
 a[type="text"]{
    width:100% !important;
     line-height:30px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a PHP question, although you use PHP to generate it. You should add the generated HTML to the question.

Comment: Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You also should have unique names for each `name` attribute. When your form is processed you won't be able to tell the difference between `form_user` and `form_name`.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am aware of the depreciated code and will fix that very soon!

Comment: If you are going to make the User and the Title smaller then would you like to make the description bigger instead ? or would you like to make the table a little smaller but keep the rest of the columns size as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **width** property to fix the width of your columns. You can apply width in html directly or using css

**HTML**

```
<td width="20%">content</td>
<th width="20%">content</th>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-class{
  width: 20%;
}

<th class="custom-class"></th>

<td class="custom-class"></td>
```

Comment: Would this be the correct way to add the class name into the th tag? <th class=custom-class>User</th>   (keeping in mind the th tag is being echoed out)

Comment: With a bit of troubleshooting, I got it to work with your solution! :) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind I would suggest some changes, see below. Check if the form action is either join, update or delete to perform the action. About the data structure you receive when the form is submitted check out the `var_dump($_POST);` part

PHP:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    font: 13px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 6px 13px;
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    font: 13px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 6px 13px;
}
thead th {
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4D5960;
    color: #ffffff;
}
tbody td {
    align: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-name">User</th>
                <th class="col-title">Title</th>
                <th class="col-description">Description</th>
                <th class="col-join">Join</th>
                <th class="col-update">Update</th>
                <th class="col-delete">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ([0, 1, 2, 3] as $row) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-name">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user[id][]" value="">
                    <input type="text" name="user[name][]" value="" size="10">
                </td>
                <td class="col-title">
                    <input type="text" name="user[title][]" value="" size="10">
                </td>
                <td class="col-description">
                    <input type="text" name="user[description][]" value="" size="10">
                </td>
                <td class="col-join">
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="join">Join</button>
                </td>
                <td class="col-update">
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">Update</button>
                </td>
                <td class="col-delete">
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for the suggestion, will change my code to follow suit with your one :)

Comment: Does it help you? I'm glad you like it :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is no problem, everything is the same

```
table {

   width: 100%;
   font: 17px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   align: center;
     } 
  input {
    width: 100%;
   font: 13px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   align: center;
   height: auto; 
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  th {
   align:center;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #4D5960;
   color: white;
    }
  tr {background-color: #f2f2f2}

  input[type="text"]{width:100% !important; line-height:30px; box-sizing:border-box;}
  a[type="text"]{width:100% !important; line-height:30px; box-sizing:border-box;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1qy5v05p/6/

you can also use Bootstrap 4, maybe it will be better https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms.asp

Comment: I've changed the CSS around so much trying to achieve what I have stated in this post but have had no luck. I don't want everything to be the same, I want to reduce the width of just the Title and User column in the table, would you possibly know how to achieve this? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of jQuery table plugins. Check [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/12-amazing-jquery-tables/) out.

My favourites are `DataTables`, `x-Editable` and `Bootgrid`. There are also open sources, you can see them with their Github repo.